# React Native redux axios mongoDB issue

Tags: mongodb, react-native, redux, axios

So, I'm having a problem with redux and axios. I usually use Fetch API. Form data won't post to mongoDb collection "postmessages". I realize I'm posting a lot of code below, but I honestly can't figure out why this is posting nothing at all to MongoDB. Below is my form with the function of handleSubmit()

Form.js

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, ActivityIndicator, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native'
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { createPost } from '../../actions/posts'

const Form = ({ navigation })=> {

    const [postData, setPostData] =  useState({
      creator: '', title: ''
      
    })
    

    console.log(postData)
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    

  const handleSubmit = async ()=>{
    
    dispatch(createPost(postData))
    
    console.log('supposed to have sent')  
   
  }

return(
...some code here

 <View style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
          <TextInput placeholder='Enter Creator'
          value={postData.creator}
          onChangeText={(value)=>setPostData({ ...postData, creator: value })}
          />
        </View>
      <View style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
          <TextInput placeholder='Enter Title'
          value={postData.title}
          onChangeText={(value)=>setPostData({ ...postData, title: value })}
          />
      </View>
          <Text
            onPress={()=> handleSubmit()}>
            Add Post
          </Text>

...some code here
)
```

Below is the actions

actions/posts.js

```
import * as api from '../api'

...some getPosts code here...

export const createPost = (post)=> async (dispatch)=>{
    try{
        const { data } = await api.createPost(post)
        dispatch({ type: 'CREATE', payload: data })
    } catch(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

Below is the api/index.js. I'm wondering if the problem may be here. I am building this on Android, however, so the url should be fine.

```
import axios from 'axios'

const url = 'http://10.0.2.2:3000/posts'

export const fetchPosts = ()=> axios.get(url)
export const createPost = (newPost)=> axios.post(url, newPost)
```

Below is the reducers. I don't think there's a problem here, but I'm including it just in case.

```
export default (posts = [], action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case 'FETCH_ALL':
            return action.payload
        case 'CREATE':
            return [ ...posts, action.payload ];
        default:
            return posts
    }
}
```

Here's the model. I've cut it down to just "title" and "creator" so as to limit the amount of code.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt")


const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    
    creator: String,
    
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: new Date()
    }
})

mongoose.model("PostMessage", postSchema)
```

Here's backend index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const port = 3000
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const helmet = require('helmet')
const morgan = require('morgan')

require('./db')
require('./models/postMessage')

const postRoutes = require('./routes/postRoutes')

//requireToken skipped
app.use(express.json())
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use('/posts', postRoutes)

app.use(helmet())
app.use(morgan('common'))

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Server is running on port " + port)
})
```

Here's "routes/postRoutes" that index.js refers to

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

const getPosts = require('../controllers/routes')
const createPost = require('../controllers/routes')

router.get('/', getPosts)
router.post('/', createPost)

module.exports = router
```

Finally, here's what the routes in "controllers/routes" look like.

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const PostMessage = mongoose.model('PostMessage')

...some getPosts route code here....
 
const createPost = async (req, res)=>{
    const body = req.body
    const newPost = new PostMessage(post)
    try{
        await newPost.save()
        res.status(201).json(newPost)
    } catch(error){
        res.status(409).json({ message: error.message })
    }
}

module.exports = [ getPosts, createPost ]
```

My db.js connectivity is working fine, so I won't include that code. If you can't find an issue in the code above, then I'll probably go back to using Fetch. Hope you see what I'm not seeing.

Comment: Are you using the stand-alone react native debugger ( https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger ) by any chance? It has a known issue where HTTP POST requests suddenly have an empty body if you inspect network requests. That particular issue is caused by the debugger and does not occur otherwise.